# Error al generar Link de libreria React-Native

Tags: react-native

Estoy realizando una app en React-Native (**react-native-cli: 2.0.1**).

Al tratar de instalar y generar el link de la libreria **Vector-icons**, me arroja estos errores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El primer error me lo arroja al tratar de instalar la librería. y el segundo error lo lanza cuando trato de generar el Link de la libreria este es el comando que utilizo:`react-native link react-native-vector-icons`.

por cierto utilizo Genymotion para emular el dispositivo android.

Comment: Son warnings no errores, podrías continuar sin problema. Si hay un problema al querer hacer `react-native link`, no lo puedes hacer si creaste tu proyecto utilizando `create-react-native-app Proyecto`, tienes que hacer "eject" primero. Si no has avanzado mucho con el proyecto lo mas simple es empezar de nuevo con `react-native init Proyecto`, si no las opciones son: 1) Buscar otra librería que no tenga código nativo, 2) Hacer **["eject"](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md)**

Comment: hola amigo estoy empezando con React-naive. podrias ser especifijo con lo de "eject"

Comment: Basicamente es "expulsar" la aplicación de `Create React Native App`, este link te explica como hacerlo: [Ejecting from Create React Native App](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md).

Comment: De hecho si pensabas lanzar las aplicaciones a sus respectivas tiendas lo tenias que hacer eventualmente

Comment: Debes agregarla de manera manual, tuve ese mismo problema con esa libreria, ahi hay un ejemplo de linking manual https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot/issues/160